# Code optimization for toggling visibility

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-events

OK, so here's my problem, folks.  I'm working on a site on which people can register for (x).  I have a drop-down menu of states for people to select.  Based on their selection of a state, I have another list of hospitals from which to choose that depends on their selection of the state.  So, if you choose Hawaii, you will only see hospitals in Hawaii and not Texas, for instance.  I have a function that toggles visibility based on the value of a check box, but I cannot seem to get it to work for the value of a drop-down.  Any thoughts?   If there is a quicker or more industry-standard way to solve it, any steering in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

What I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{  $('#stateinjured').change(function()
    {  
        $('#stateinjuredky').toggle(this.checked); 
    }); 

});
```

```
<select>
<option selected="selected">Select your state</option>
    <option id="stateinjured" >Kentucky</option>
    <option>West Virginia</option>
    <option>Ohio</option>
    <option>Tennessee</option>
    </select><br/>
<select>
<option style="display:none;" id="stateinjuredky" selected="selected">Choose hospital you visited</option>
    <option>hospital1</option>
    <option>hospital2</option>
    <option>hospital3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an AJAX call to fill the hospitals list?

Comment: i would love to know how to do that, but i don't :/.  just started using j query. plus, this computer doesn't have admin rights and i can't install apache on it. i could test the ajax on my website, though

Comment: The ajax call isn't needed unless this is being database driven. It SHOULD be database driven, but it isn't otherwise required. Ajax is very useful, it basically lets you remote call another file, be it HTML, text, PHP, or something else. I would suggest you spend about 2 hours total looking into JSON and finding out how `$.ajax()` works. ---- If this is a school project or something, you can just make a javascript array of the hospitals instead of resorting to ajax calls. --- I'm only saying you don't need ajax because it's important to know what ajax is for, rather than how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into jQuery's AJAX, it's fast and you don't need a local server to use it, you could use your web server.

look over here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: so there's not a good, jQuery fix then?  how much time does it take to get familiar enough with AJAX to perform this cascading dropdown stuff?

Comment: If you want to fix this with jQuery you would end up coding for ages while you can just create an AJAX function in the blink of an eye. With the jquery.com website ready it won't take very long to get to know the AJAX syntax and usage :) Try it ;)

Comment: ok, but if i can't figure it out i'm going to bug you! :). thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the id's and style on the wrong elements. You'd also need some logic to determine what was selected and then show the proper list. The code below will only show 1 select box on page load, and then depending on what is selected will show the requested list:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#stateinjured').change(function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this + "option:selected").val();
        if (selectedOption == "Kentucky") {
            $("#stateinjuredky").css("display","block");
        }
        //or you could just have the select ids be the state names, then you wouldn't need all these if...else statements
    }); 
});
```

Then...

```
<select id="stateinjured">
    <option selected="selected">Select your state</option>
    <option>Kentucky</option>
    <option>West Virginia</option>
    <option>Ohio</option>
    <option>Tennessee</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="stateinjuredky" style="display: none;">
    <option selected="selected">Choose hospital you visited</option>
    <option>hospital1</option>
    <option>hospital2</option>
    <option>hospital3</option>
</select>
<!-- more selects for other states -->
```

There are definitely more efficient ways of doing this though, as others have said.

Comment: can you point me in the right direction as to what one of those might be (save the AJAX, which i am looking into)?

Comment: No, the ajax is mostly what I'm referring to. You'd have a second page that generates the lists based on a passed parameter. Then you could have a div or something in which you'd load the data from that second page. Using the jQuery load statement, you can load page fragments and pass arrays of data to the server for processing. http://api.jquery.com/load/